# Electron-Python Application with Excel Spreadsheet as Database : Using npm package - database-js-xlsx for CRUD Operations

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, excel, electron

I am working on this package for developing an application in Electron-Python framework with Excel Spreadsheet as Database
I am getting below error,

```
**(node:14796) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: Invalid string length
at ..\node_modules\database-js-xlsx\index.js:507:63
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:14796) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14796) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.**
```

When I try hitting node --unhandled-rejections=strict .js

```
    **..\node_modules\database-js-xlsx\index.js:507
                            sql = sql.substr(0, err.offset) + '.' + sql.substr(err.offset + 1);
                                                                  ^
    RangeError: Invalid string length**
```

Can someone help me out?

Below is my code,

```
**var database = require('database-js-xlsx/index');
var connection = database.open({ Database: 'yields.xlsx' });
function handleError(error) {
    console.log("ERROR:", error);
    process.exit(1);
}
connection.query("SELECT a,b FROM Sheet1$A1:C4 Where c= 'Apples' ").then((data) => {
    console.log(data[0].a)
    if (data.length != 1) {
        handleError(new Error("Invalid data returned"));
    }
    else{
        console.log(data)
    }
    connection.close().then(() => {
        process.exit(0);
    }).catch(handleError);
}).catch(handleError);**
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be querying a cell not a sheet.

Try `SELECT a,b FROM Sheet1 Where c= 'Apples'`

Also I get the impression that the columns should be named rather than addressed.

So if a,b,c were your column names I would expect them to be labeled in your first row. Not sure on this...

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."